# My solution for google codejam Foregone Solution is showing wrong, why?

Tags: python

This is the link to the problem and I've given my code below, I know its right but the google code jam shows that my code gives wrong answer.

https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/0000000000088231#problem

This is my code :

```
x = input()
a = ''
b = ''
for i in x:
    if i == "4":
        a+='3'
        b+='1'
    else:
        a+=i
        b+='0'
print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
T = int(input())
for x in range(1, T + 1):
    N = input()
    A, B = ''
    for c in N:
        if c == '4':
            A += '3'
            B += '1'
        else:
            A += c
            B += '0'
    print(f'Case #{x}: {A} {int(B)}')
```

You need either `int(B)` or `B.strip('0')` because there could be some leading zeros. Also, don't forget to print `"Case #x: "` before your A and B numbers.